# Conditional expression in verlog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I want to know how the synthesizer in VIVADO will understand the conditional operator in verlig. An expression like: A = X ? Y : -Y will contain any multiplier since there is the negative sign in the second branch. Does it do first the multiplication of (-1)*Y or it won't use any multiplier at all in hardware.

Regards,
Jet

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't use any multiplier. You'll get a following structure:

[image]

As you can see, only one mux and one adder (to achieve two's complement) are used.